# Starting Process from IIS as Admin User

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I have been working on an issue with a code move from Windows Server 2008 to 2012 for about a week. I have done a ton of searching and nothing addresses the problem I am seeing.

I am working on a web app I have taken over from another developer who recently left the company. The app uses fabric.js to allow the user to manipulate a canvas. Later, it makes a PDF by rendering the canvas to a base64 string, converting it to an image in .Net, then adding the image via iTextSharp to the PDF.

Since this process can take a while, (planned to be done in larger page sets) and would interfere with the user, and is probably too much responsibility to happen in a separate tab in the clients browser, the original developer came up with a method that pulls the canvas data from a database, then rebuilds the canvas at the desired page dimensions and scale for print on the server via IE.

So, the .Net code starts an IE process with the a URL argument that opens IE to the same page the original editor made there changes in. This instance of the browser opens on the server with parameters that allow it to obtain the needed data in Print mode for a full sized document render. The browser renders the page and a base64 image string is produced, set to a hidden field, then posted back to the server for processing into a PDF. That process is initiated via AJAX and the server acknowledges with a URL to the PDF. The browser is redirected though JavaScript to that document.

Honestly, to me this all seems very cumbersome, but I have no better thoughts and it did in fact work on our staging server.

This week, it was decided to move the latest version to the clients new server. While our staging server is running Windows 2008 Server, the new one is 2012. This is where the problem starts.

It is using the following (kind of, explained later) to open the process
(*note: userAccount is obtained by a simple function that populates a dynamic ExpanoObject with the SecureString and the UserName values that are known to be good.):

```
String path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        //FileName = "IEXPLORE",
        FileName = path,
        Arguments = "https://www.google.com",//REAL URL REMOVED
        //Password = (userAccount.password as SecureString),
        //UserName = userAccount.account.ToString(),
        //Domain = "MYCURRENTDOMAIN",//REAL DOMAIN REMOVED
        //UseShellExecute = false,
        //RedirectStandardOutput = true
    };
```

What I am seeing on the server is that this code runs right through, without starting the process. There is no error, and observing the server processes shows IE does not open, even if I intentionally hang it inside the using statement. My assumption was that the IIS user did not have permission to start a desktop application and it was silently failing. This lead me to add the commented code.

Before I addressed a test on the 2012 server, I decided that I should create a local user for a test. Give them admin permission, then try to launch IE with 'elevated' permissions via that user, assuming the reason the process was not launching on the 2012 server was a stricter security environment. 
When I added the username and password, the process erred saying I needed to set UseShellExecute to false if declaring a user. When I examined the ProcessStartInfo constructor overloads, I saw that when creating it by user, a domain was required (For: LDAP?, ASP?, tested with both same result). However, this configuration does not allow (me to observe) the IE process launch when observed via taskman in a Windows 7 dev environment, 2008 or 20012 server.

To define the problem, I can undo all the comments and it will fail. I can run as is, it does not fail. I can un-comment only UseShellExecute and it fails the same as if I also include the username and password. When I observe the ProcessStartInfo in Visual Studio debug, I see the correct values.

So, I think I have several related questions, boiling down to: "OMG! plz help with the server move". Why does the process start fine in Server 2008 without defining UseShellExecute = false or a UserName/Password/Domain combo, but succeed if I do not address it at all knowing the default is true/NullOrEmpty respectively.

The next is, would I need to define any additional permissions for my new Admin user who's credentials I would use to allow this to occur under Windows 2008 or 2012 server? Would the Admin user need to have permissions defined along the path it would operate under or something similar because the admin group privilege is nerfed? (Am I wrong to assume that I can test Windows 7 with higher security settings and it would fail here, but not there, thought clearly offered through the API for both environments, as it compiles and all?)

Is it possible that this process, being not shell started, is being started, but not finishing, and that it's hidden within the app pool's worker process and I need to think apppools?

Of course, anything I have not thought which might be helpful is also welcome.

Comment: I was able to work around this specific problem without calling to open a process. Instead I will use a scheduled task to open an aspx file within the site. I created a page that will read from the database, and process a schedule of rendering. Its load grabs the data needed to process the job and places it in session. Then it posts pack to itself and processes the actual rendering. The images are stored, pdfs created from them, then removed all within IIS. I am not answering my own question because I would still like to understand why this was not working. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I just found this post. It is not exactly my issue, but more similar than not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384234/c-sharp-app-hangs-randomly-when-called-from-process-start

Answer (score 0):

The reason this did not work is that the IIS was not given sufficient permissions to carry out the commands. IIS should not have the permissions.

We instead wrote a little console app that works in tandem with a scheduled task. The task runs the rout. The console app monitors the system and is capable of killing bad processes, so good ones can run next time.

The scheduled task allowed me to start a process under a specific user, with appropriate permissions.
The console app allowed me to observer the process, and clean up when tasks errored or could not finish. Task scheduler would never get back a done code. Launching a tabbed browser spawns a parent of the window you will view. Killing a tab never destroys that parent. The console app could.

In hind site, I could have done it all in the console app, but it's kind of an animal that grew itself and I intend to simplify.